# nodejs azure application throwing errors about javascript syntax that do not occur in localhost environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I have a simple one-page screenshot app  using puppeteer/headless chrome that works fine in localhost.

When I run it in azure, page fails to load due to server error.

When I check the logs, I get 'unexpected token' errors on what looks like valid javascript and must be valid since it runs fine local.

Using the line numbers in error logs as a guide,
I re-wrote the code in different formats, trying to work-around the issue.
Conde runs fine local every time, but in azure, the exception just moves to a different line.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

**code of file that is throwing errors:**

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var awsConfig = require('aws-config');
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs')
var request = require("request");
var router = express.Router();
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');



var screenshot = async function (req) {

    var appUrl = "x";

    if (req.query.localHost) {
        appUrl = "x";
    }

    var url = appUrl + "x";


    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1600, height: 900 });

    var path = "x";

    try {

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });

        page.on('console', function (msg) {
            if (msg.text === "all are done") {
                (async () => {

                    //  console.log(msg.text);

                    await page.screenshot({ path: path, type: "jpeg", quality: 90 });

                    var fileName = "x";

                    saveAutoGenThumbnail(fileName, fs.createReadStream(path), function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {

                        } else {
                            //fs.unlink(path);
                            fs.unlinkSync(path);
                        }
                    });

                    await browser.close();

                })();
            }

        });


    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }


}

function saveAutoGenThumbnail(imageName, imageFile, callBack) {

    AWS.config.accessKeyId = "x";
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "x";
    AWS.config.region = "x";

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'x' } })

    var data = {
        Key: imageName, Body: imageFile, ACL: 'public-read', ContentType: "image/jpeg"
    };

    s3Bucket.putObject(data, callBack);

}


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

   // screenshot(req);

    res.render('screenshot', { title: 'screenshot' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**web config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your Node.js application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=290972
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- mimeMap enables IIS to serve particular file types as specified by fileExtension. -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"/>


    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />


    </handlers>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />


        <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you [specified the Node.js version in Azure](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps.md)?

Comment: I just checked and it was set in package.json to  "node": "~6.10.x"  I checked node version in command line and updated the  package.json value to  "node": "8.9.1" I still get   "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: Trying to [enable logging of stdout and stderr](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/08/19/debug-node-js-web-apps-on-azure/) and see what logs say.

Comment: I 've been checking the log stream. The issue seems related to async functions. right now, the error  thrown is this:  async function screenshot(req) {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Comment: Can you show your code and the web.config file?

Comment: I am editing the question to include code. replaced some strings with "x" To  the troll who downvoted this question with no explanation: please explain yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Async functions are [not supported by Node.js versions older than version `7.6`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/).
2. Azure Web Apps currently doesn't support Node.js `8.9.1`. You can check all available versions in Azure via `https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime`.

So, to avoid this error, you'll need to set the Node.js version to `8.9.0` instead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I changed to 8.9.0 in package.json  and then in app settings as you described.  Problem solved!