# Async/Await not running in Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, asynchronous, backend

Within my Azure App Service Node.js backend I cannot seem to get the Javascript async/await feature to run. I have [changed the default version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47647152/9258361) within application settings and package.json to above 7.6. (Changed to 8.9.0)

I would like to use this feature within a custom Express router shown here:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).send('GET: This is a test response!');
});

router.post('/:id', async function (req, res, next) { 
    var context = req.azureMobile;

    var newLovedOne = req.body.lovedone;        
    var newTie = req.body.tie;

    console.log('POST: newLovedOne ', newLovedOne);
    console.log('POST: newTie ', newTie);

    try {
        await context.tables('Tie').insert(newTie);
        await context.tables('LovedOne').insert(newLovedOne);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('Insert failed!');
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Attempting to start the app with the above router produces this:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:12:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify whether the Node.js version is correctly set, you can go to your root and open the `iisnode.yml` file. Make sure it has the following line with the correct version:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.9.0\node.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you, Aaron, that is what I needed! Is that the standard process when you wish to run a different version of Node.js to change it in all three locations? (Application settings, `package.json` file, and `iisnode.yml` file)